# How to make a terracotta block with specific placing properties

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to create a custom map where colored terracotta can only be placed on other terracotta blocks of the same color, but I don't know the command.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not specify data values with `CanPlaceOn` which rules out being selective of color or any other block variant.

The closest you can get is a white terracotta block that can only be placed on a dyed terracotta block of any color.

If that works, here is the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stained_hardened_clay"]}
```

Comment: This isn't going to be an issue in 1.13, but unfortunately, that's still a ways off, even for snapshots.